# How to retrieve elements of an array from a python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary generated using code.It's in this format

```
{
  (127016, 2015, 'FY'): {
    'id': array([], dtype=int32),
    'index': {
      ('ID698971838', 'OR'): {
        'id': array([], dtype=int32),
      'elems': {
        ('PCT_AP_CUST_ID', 'I'): array([-1])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my first 3 elements of Dictionary

```
[((701091, 2013, 'FY'),
  {'id': array([], dtype=int90),
   'APs': {('AP010977414', 'OR'): {'id': array([], dtype=int90),
     'elems': {('M_Group_CUST_ID', 'I'): array([-1]),
      ('ISO_AP', 'I'): array([-1])}}}}),
 ((701111, 2013, 'FY'),
  {'id': array([], dtype=int90),
   'APs': {('AP911117711', 'OR'): {'id': array([], dtype=int90),
     'elems': {('ISO_AP', 'I'): array([-1])}}}}),
 ((701077, 2013, 'FY'),
  {'id': array([], dtype=int90),
   'APs': {('AP090419711', 'OR'): {'id': array([], dtype=int90),
     'elems': {('M_CTL_SELL_TYP',
       'I'): array([     -1,   99919,   99970,   74071,   10909,   11910,  991997,
              991994,  991999,  997000,  997001,  997000,  997009,  997001,
              997007,  997001,  997007,  997004,  997009,  997010,  997011,
              997010,  997019,  997011,  997017,  997011,  997017,  997014,
              997019,  997000,  997001,  997000,  997009,  997001,  997007,
              997001,  997007,  997004,  997009,  997090,  997091,  997090,
              997099,  997091,  997097,  997091,  997097,  997094,  997099,
              997010,  997011,  997010,  997019,  997011,  997017,  997011,
              997017,  997014,  997019,  997070,  997071,  997070,  997079,
              997071,  997077,  997071,  997077,  997074,  997079,  997010,
              997011,  997010,  997019,  997011,  997017,  997011,  997017,
              997014,  997019,  997070,  997901,  997907,  997904,  997909,
              997990,  997991,  997990,  997999,  997991,  997997,  997991,
              997997,  997994,  997999,  997910,  997911,  997910,  997919,
              997911,  997917,  997911,  997917,  997914,  997919,  997970,
              997971,  997970,  997979,  997971,  997977,  997971,  997977,
              997974,  997979,  997910,  994744,  994749,  994790,  994791,
              994790,  994799,  994791,  994797,  994791,  994797,  994794,
              994799,  994400,  994401,  994400,  994409,  994401,  994407,
              994401,  994407,  994404,  994409,  994410,  994411,  994410,
              994419,  994411,  994417,  994411,  994417,  994414,  994419,
              994400,  994401,  994400,  994409,  994401,  994407,  994401,
              994407,  994404,  994409,  994490,  994491,  994490,  994499,
              994491,  994497,  994491,  994497,  994494,  994499,  994410,
              994411,  994410,  994419,  994411,  994417,  994411,  994417,
              999011,  999017,  999014,  999019,  999070,  999071,  999070,
              910997,  910994,  910999,  910910,  910911,  910910,  910919,
              910911,  910917,  910911,  910917,  910914,  910919,  910970,
              910971,  910970,  910979,  910971,  910977,  910971,  910977,
              910974,  910979,  910910,  910911,  910910,  910919,  910911,
              910917,  910911,  910917,  910914,  910919,  910970,  910971,
              910970,  910979,  910971,  910977,  910971,  910977,  910974,
              910979,  910940,  910941,  910940,  910949,  910941,  910947,
              910941,  910947,  910944,  910949,  910990,  910991,  910990,
              910999,  910991,  910997,  910991,  910997,  910994,  910999,
              910100,  910101,  910100,  910109,  910101,  910107,  910101,
              910107,  910104,  970140,  970149,  970141,  970147,  971107,
              971101,  977471,  977470,  977479,  977471,  977477,  977471,
              977477,  977474,  977479,  977410,  977411,  977410,  977419,
              977411,  977417,  977411,  977417,  977414,  977419,  977470,
              977471,  977470,  977479,  977471,  977477,  977471,  977477,
              977474,  977479,  977440,  977441,  977440,  977449,  977441,
              977447,  977441,  977447,  977444,  977449,  977490,  977491,
              977490,  977499,  977491,  977497,  977491,  977497,  977494,
              977499,  977900,  977901,  977900,  977909,  977901,  977907,
              977901,  977907,  977904,  977909,  977910,  977911,  977910,
              977919,  977911,  977917,  977911,  977917,  977914,  977919,
              977900,  977901,  977900,  977909,  977901,  977907,  977901,
              977907,  977904,  977909,  977990,  977991,  977990,  977999,
              977991,  977997,  977991,  977997,  977994,  977097,  977091,
              977097,  977094,  977099,  977100,  977101,  977100,  977109,
              977101,  977107,  977101,  977107,  977104,  977109,  977110,
              977111,  977110,  977119,  977111,  977117,  977111,  977117,
              977114,  977119,  977100,  977101,  977100,  977109,  977101,
              977107,  977101,  977107,  977104,  977109,  977190,  977191,
              977190,  977199,  977191,  977197,  977191,  977197,  977194,
              977199,  977110,  977111,  977110,  977119,  977111,  977117,
              977111,  977117,  977114,  977119,  977170,  977171,  977170,
              977179,  977171,  977177,  977171,  977177,  977174,  977179,
              977110,  977111,  977110,  977119,  977111,  977117,  977111,
              977117,  977114,  977119,  977170,  977171,  977170,  977179,
              977171,  977177,  977171,  977177,  977174,  977117,  977111,
              977117,  977114,  977119,  977100,  977101,  977100,  977109,
              977101,  977107,  977101,  977107,  977104,  977109,  977190,
              977191,  977190,  977199,  977191,  977197,  977191,  977197,
              977194,  977199,  977110,  977111,  977110,  977119,  977111,
              977117,  977111,  977117,  977114,  977119,  977170,  977171,
              977170,  977179,  977171,  977177,  977171,  977177,  977174,
              977179,  977110,  911700,  911701,  911700,  911709,  911701,
              911707,  911701,  911707,  911704,  911709,  911790,  911791,
              911790,  911799,  911791,  911797,  911791,  911797,  911794,
              911799,  911710,  911711,  911710,  911719,  911711,  911717,
              911711,  911717,  911714,  911719,  911770,  911771,  911770,
              911779,  911771,  911777,  911771,  911777,  911774,  911779,
              911710,  911711,  911710,  911719,  911711,  911717,  911711,
              911717,  911714,  911719,  911770,  911771,  911770,  911779,
              911771,  970779,  970771,  970777,  971191,  971197,  971191,
              971197,  971194,  971199,  971700,  971701,  971700,  971709,
              971701,  971707,  971701,  971707,  971704,  971709,  971710,
              971711,  971710,  971719,  971711,  971717,  971711,  971717,
              971714,  971719,  971700,  971701,  971700,  971709,  971701,
              971707,  971701,  941141,  941147,  941141,  941147,  949104,
              949109,  949110,  949111,  949110,  949119,  949111,  949117,
              949111,  949117,  949114,  949119,  949100,  949101,  949100,
              949109,  949101,  949107,  949101,  949107,  949104,  949109,
              949190,  100107,  100101,  100107,  100104,  100109,  100110,
              100111,  100110,  100119,  100111,  100117,  100111,  100117,
              100114,  100119,  100100,  100101,  100100,  100109,  100101,
              100107,  100101,  100107,  100104,  100109,  100190,  100191,
              100190,  100199,  100191,  100197,  100191,  100197,  100194,
              100199,  100110,  100111,  100110,  100119,  100111,  100117,
              100111,  100117,  100114,  100119,  100170,  100171,  100170,
              100179,  100171,  100177,  100171,  100177,  100174,  100179,
              101117,  101114,  101119,  101170,  101171,  101170,  101179,
              101171,  101177,  101171,  101177,  101174,  101179,  101140,
              101141,  101140,  101149,  101141,  101147,  101141,  101147,
              101144,  101149,  101190,  101191,  101190,  101199,  101191,
              101197,  101191,  101197,  101194,  101199,  101000,  101001,
              101000,  101009,  101001,  101007,  101001,  101007,  101004,
              101009,  101010,  101011,  101010,  101019,  101011,  101017,
              101011,  101017,  101014,  101019,  101000,  101001,  101000,
              101009,  101001,  101007,  101001,  101007,  101004,  101009,
              101090,  101091,  101090,  101099,  101091,  101097,  101091,
              101097,  101094, 1111971, 1111970, 1111979, 1111971, 1111977,
             1111971, 1170904, 1170909, 1170990, 1170991, 1119410, 1119411,
             1119410, 1119419, 1114994, 1114999, 1114910, 1114911, 1177710,
             1177711, 1177710, 1177719, 1177711, 1177717, 1149977, 1149971,
             1149977, 1149974, 1191091, 1191097, 1191094, 1191099, 1000077,
             1000074, 1000079, 1000010, 1000011, 1000010, 1011199, 1011700,
             1011701, 1011700, 1011709, 1114077, 1479104, 1479109, 1479110,
             1479111, 1479110, 1479119, 1440104, 1440109, 1440190, 1440114,
             1440119, 1440100, 1440101, 1440100, 1440109, 1447091, 1447097,
             1447091, 1444971, 1444977, 1444974, 1444979, 1444940, 1444941,
             1444940, 1901099, 1901100, 1901101, 1901100, 1919797, 1919791,
             1919797, 1919794, 1919799, 1900001, 1900007, 1900001, 1900007,
             1900004, 1900199, 1900110, 1900111, 1900110, 1900119, 9097417,
             9104979, 9110477, 9110471, 9117997, 9111077, 9010799, 9019109,
             9017471, 9077977]),
      ('ISO_AP', 'I'): array([-1])}}}})]
```

I want to retrieve each element under key id separately & store it in a python data frame  along with the first value of first key. For example say for the first value of first key is 127016 & I have ID array contains value 2,7,9,11. So my data frame will look like

```
Group   ID
127016  2
127016  7
127016  9
127016  11
```

Can you please suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Can you explain why your dictionary is like this to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to index by part of a tuple, because the dict indexing is done by hash. Therefore you have to iterate over all keys.

There is not enough information to know exactly what you want. Are the keys repeated, will there ever only be one match?

```
d = {} # your data
keys = [key for key in d if key[0]==127016]
```

Then it's just a matter of iterating over the matching keys:

```
ids = [ d[key]['id'] for key in keys ]
```

or

```
ids = [ id for id in d[key]['id'] for key in keys ]
```

If you don't want list comprehensions:

```
for key in d:
    if key[0]==127016:
       for id in d[key]['id']:
           print 127016, id
```

Comment: Any suggestion please?